# Why would Azure Devops pipelines be unable to connect to my Python/Linux function app?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-linux

**Update** *It is happening again. Successfully-created Windows-hosted function, visible in the Azure portal. Can connect to other functions in the same subscription and resource group, from the same pipeline, using the same service connection - but this newly-created function is invisible to the pipeline. What's going on?*

**Update** *Now we have the same issue with a newly-created function on windows. No visibility of it to DevOps after several hours. What might be going on?*

My deployment pipeline is failing, claiming it cannot find a specific azure function app.

If I try to use the helper, it too cannot find the app:
[image]
[image]

A similar pipeline to a windows function app in the same resource group works correctly.

Things I've checked/tried:

- The service connection is in the Contributor role for the Linux function
- The pipeline is authorised to use the service connection
- I've tried adding a new service connection, scoped to the specific resource group
- I've tried deleting the original app and creating a new Linux function app with a different name
- The target function app was created more than half an hour ago
- We have a development environment set up with separate Azure Devops and a different subscription - here the same deployment pipeline works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About two hours after creation, the function finally appeared (with no changes on our part). I assume there must have been some kind of lag in the process of making the new function app visible to DevOps. Marking this as answered but leaving it up, in case others have similar issues.